# Android device reboots after gdbserver attached to any process

Tags: android, android-ndk, linux-kernel, gdb

I am currently trying do some debugging work with `ndk-gdb` on a old Android device (Android 2.2, kernel 2.6.32) from usb interface. Every time `gdbserver` attached any process, the device reboots, like below:

```
sh-3.2# lib/gdbserver --debug :9999 --attach 479  
lib/gdbserver --debug :9999 --attach 479  
sigchld_handler  
Attached; pid = 479  
linux_wait: [Process 479]  
linux_wait_for_lwp: <all threads>  
my_waitpid (-1, 0x40000000)  
my_waitpid (-1, 0x1): status(137f), 479  
Got an event from 479 (137f)
```

...device reboots now

I found no clue in `/proc/kmsg` and `/data/system/dropbox`.
Is it related to watchdog or some other kernel config?
In the kernel config file, there is:

```
#CONFIG_MSM_SERIAL_DEBUGGER is not set  
CONFIG_MSM_RPCSERVER_WATCHDOG=y
```

Are they relevant?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer now. 
The device use an old cpu MSM7225 which has no VFP, but the kernel has VFP built in.
When gdbserver is attaching some process, it will try to get some register sets in the devices. When retrieving the VFP registers which doesn't exist, system reboots.
Solution: comment out VFP support on kernel configuration.
Now ndk-gdb works.